# how to give listView this shadow style?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-styles

I need to give shadow effect to my list view.

below is the image what i want.

[scerrnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVa1.png)

My main activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jiq.sagar.javainterviewquestion.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/windows_title"
    android:id="@+id/include" />

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/include"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#e4e3e6"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:divider="#9f9b9b"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and my textview which i am setting dynamically from code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#1e1d1d"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
```

and my code where i am setting listview and textview

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview, mainList);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: it can be done using [card view](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).give elevation to card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
}
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#1e1d1d"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope this helps you.you can change the size of elevation

```
android:elevation="3dp"
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to android. Where is my listview in your example?

Comment: this is `list_item.xml` where you created the dynamic code of your **textview**.list view will remain in your `activity.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Put you TextView inside a CardView. That is not a shadow effect it is a CardView. Also add some margin to it.

If you are not familiar with CardView this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) might help you.

Also after inserting the TextView inside a CardView you will not be able to use ArrayAdapter directly to set your ListView. So to do that you will have to create a custom adapter. For which you can check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

Answer (score 1):

add this to your textview `android:elevation="4dp"`